# Passing function parameters only works in Firefox

Tags: javascript

This is probably really simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am querying data from Firebase and then I am trying to pass the parameters to a function called `createPostElement` that creates my HTML elements.
For some reason my code only works in Firefox.

Passing data from the `dbRefObject` doesen't seem to work. No errors, nothing.

```
function createPostElement(title, categories, audio, key, thumbnail) {
  var html = '<div class="title">' + title +'</div>';
  var container = document.getElementById('page-content');
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

function startDatabaseQueries() {
  // Create reference
  const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('podcasts');

  // Sync object changes
  var fetchPosts = function() {
    dbRefObject.on('child_added', function(snap) {
      createPostElement(snap.val().title, snap.val().categories, snap.val().audio, snap.key, snap.val().thumbnail);
    });
  };

  // Fetching and displaying all posts of each sections.
  fetchPosts();
}

startDatabaseQueries();
```

Comment: I'd place a debugger statement inside the event handler, but before your call to createPostElement and see what your references point to before being passed to the function.

Comment: So you're saying that if you don't pass any arguments, then the function works? And if you do pass arguments, even simple primitives, it still doesn't work?

Comment: And what does "works" mean in this context? Are you just seeing no display? Is the function not invoked at all? If so, how are you verifying this? I don't see any logging in your code sample.

Comment: The function works well in Firefox. The data is passed and rendered on the page. Even console log inside "dbRefObject" doesen't display on Edge, Chrome and Safari

Comment: I just found out that it was authentication problem. There is nothing wrong with the code. I was only authenticated in Firefox - silly me.  Thank you anyway!